# Is it possible to group jqGrid column?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I need to group three columns header to one column in jqGrid, Is it possible?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

Currently grouping is not supported, but it will probably be the top feature (along with Excel export) for the next versions of the product. There is a poll in the blog home-page with “Which Feature Do You Need” question – you can vote there for your favourite feature.

[@jqForums](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/about-grouping-column-header/)

Answer (score 0):

its still not supported in jqGrid officially, here is the workaround,

[jQgrid: multiple column row headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712763/jqgrid-multiple-column-row-headers/5710119#5710119)

Working example posted by @Oleg

http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridHeaders3.htm