# jQgrid: multiple column row headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to extend my jQGrid to have multiple rows for the header.

It will look something like this

> ```
>                -----------------------
> Level 1 - >    | Application         |
>                -----------------------  
> Level 2 - >    |Code    | Name       |  
>                -----------------------
>                | 0002827| Mobile Phone1
>                | 0202827| Mobile Phone2
>                | 0042827| Mobile Phon3e
>                | 0005827| Mobile Phone4
>                | 0002627| Mobile Phon5e
>                | 0002877| Mobile Phone6
>                | 0002828| Mobile Phone7
> ```

I am wondering how to do this with jQGrid 3.8.2? Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is really not so easy as it looks like at first glance. I tried to find a simple solution, but the best result which I found you can see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridHeaders0.htm):
[image]

The order of the headers (level 1 and level 2) is not as one would like to have. Other attempts like [this](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridHeaders1.htm) or [this](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridHeaders2.htm) are buggy because the sorting and column resizing works not more correct.

For the understanding: the grid moves the `<thead>` **outside of** the table and places it inside of separate  which are placed above the table (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462071/jqgrid-get-th-and-thead-using-jquery/3463002#3463002) for more information). It allows including some additional information like searching toolbar **between** the table header and the table body. Other places in the jqGrid code like column resizing and column sorting works incorrect if there are exist other headers (one more `<tr>` with `<th>` elements) over the main column headers. So only the inserting of additional column headers **under** the main columns headers (which looks not nice of course) not breaks the sorting and the resizing of columns.

**UPDATED:** See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341339/jqgrid-column-group/7351638#7351638) which do provide the solution of the problem under some restrictions.

Comment: @Jonathan: In the next time I plan to examine sorting and resizing code of jqGrid more exactly and will try to fix the problem with the first row of the headers. I hope that including classes ("th.ui-th-column" instead of "th") in the lines like [this](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.0.0/js/grid.base.js#L1839) will solve the problem.

Comment: @Jonathan: I found some places in the jqGrid source code which made the problems. Look at [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridHeaders3.htm). It is not yet the final version, but many things already are working in the Internet Explorer and Firefox (not yet in Chrome).

Comment: Thanks for your enthusiasm, great solution!

Comment: @Jonathan: See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341339/jqgrid-column-group/7351638#7351638) which do provide the solution of the problem under some restrictions.

Comment: @Oleg, I did some improvemnts in the way you do it. I added a blank row in the bottom.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is a late answer but for future reference [header grouping](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3agroupingheadar) is now included in version 4.2.0 of jqGrid

Comment: I actually stopped using JQGrid as it doesnt really fit well with MVC and instead coding things by hand. I did find it very useful for CRUD type things but thats it. Thanks for feedback info!

Answer (score 2):

Modified the original idea by Oleg and made it into a function that can make several "spanned" headers:

```
function head_groups(mygrid, settings){

    var colModel, header, config, ths;

    if (typeof mygrid == 'string') mygrid = $(mygrid);

    colModel = mygrid[0].p.colModel;
    ths = mygrid[0].grid.headers;
    header = mygrid.closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view").find("table.ui-jqgrid-htable > thead");

    if (!header.children("tr.head_group").length) {
        header.find("th").attr('rowspan', 2);
        header.append('<tr class="head_group"></tr>');
    }

    for (c in settings) {

        config = settings[c]; // caption, col, span

        for(var i=0; i<colModel.length; i++) {

            if (colModel[i].name == config.col) {
                for(var s=0; s<config.span; s++) {
                    $(ths[i+s].el).removeAttr('rowspan');
                }
                i +=s; // skip unnecessary cycles
                header.children("tr.head_group").append('<th class="ui-state-default ui-th-ltr" id="span_'+config.col+'" colspan="'+config.span+'" role="columnheader">'+config.caption+'</th>');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage sample:

```
head_groups("table#results", [
    {caption: 'Test 1', col: 'num', span: 2},
    {caption: 'Result', col: 'sta', span: 3},
    {caption: 'Bla bla bla', col: 'bl2', span: 2}
]);
```

It also adds a class for the header row and IDs for the header cells for some styling or special functionality.

In fact this can be easily integrated in the jqGrid core :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Help needed in Multiple column grouping (jQGrid 3.8.2)](http://www.trirand.net/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&t=1106), the jqGrid support team indicates:

> This is currently not supported. Multiple column headers in a single column (subcolumns) are not currently a feature of jqGrid.

Comment: Thats true, I am aware of that. I am trying to find a way to achieve this. Even if its through some deviant method.

Comment: If you do get it to work, you should consider submitting a patch to the jqGrid team, so the fix can be rolled into a future release.

Comment: Ha ha Justin, brother thats why im posting! +50 Points not enought? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code of Oleg to be able to show the grouping in the first row, basically I created a dummy third row and just deleted the text in the first row.

```
var x = 0;
insertColumnGroupHeader = function (mygrid, mergeSettingList) {
    var i, cmi, skip = 0, $tr, colHeader, iCol, $th,
        colModel = mygrid[0].p.colModel,
        ths = mygrid[0].grid.headers,
        gview = mygrid.closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view"),
    thead = gview.find("table.ui-jqgrid-htable>thead");
    $tr = $("<tr>");

    var currCaption = '';
    var currColumnName = '';
    var currSpan = 0;
    var currSkip = 0;
    tr = "<tr>";
    for (i = 0; i < colModel.length; i++) {
        $th = $(ths[i].el);
        cmi = colModel[i];

        if (currSkip === 0) {
            currColumnName = '';
            for (j = 0; j < mergeSettingList.length; j++) {
                if (mergeSettingList[j].col == cmi.name) {
                    currCaption = mergeSettingList[j].caption;
                    currColumnName = mergeSettingList[j].col;
                    currSpan = mergeSettingList[j].span;
                    currWidth = mergeSettingList[j].width;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (cmi.name !== currColumnName) {
            if (currSkip === 0) {
                $th.attr("rowspan", "2");
            } else {
                // Skip part of group
                denySelectionOnDoubleClick($th);
                currSkip--;
            }
        } else {
            denySelectionOnDoubleClick($th);

            tr += '<th class="ui-state-default ui-th-ltr" colspan="' + currSpan + '" role="columnheader">' + currCaption + '</th>';
            currSkip = currSpan - 1;
        }
    }
    tr += "</tr>";
    mygrid.closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view").find("table.ui-jqgrid-htable > thead").append(tr);

    $th = $(ths[0].el);
    tr = "<tr>";
    var html = $th.parent().html();
    tr += html;
    tr += "</tr>";

    mygrid.closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view").find("table.ui-jqgrid-htable > thead").append(tr);
    for (i = 0; i < colModel.length; i++) {
        $th = $(ths[i].el);
        cmi = colModel[i];
        $th.empty();
        $th.css({"padding-top": "0px", height: "0px", border: "0px"});
    }
}
```

Sample call.

```
var mergeParam = [
        {caption: ' ', col: 'ActionKey', span: 3},
        {caption: 'Planned', col: 'PlannedStartColKey', span: 5},
        {caption: 'Actual', col: 'ActualStartColKey', span: 12}
    ];
insertColumnGroupHeader2($(GridNames.Grid), mergeParam);
```