# jqGrid "double level" of Group Headers

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

(version free jqgrid-4.13.6)

Is it possible to create a "double level" of Group Headers?

I attached image to understand my question (it's just a free drawing)

[image]

Comment: check this demo http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/ on the left go to functionality -> Group Column Headers

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712763/jqgrid-multiple-column-row-headers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can call `setGroupHeaders` **multiple times** to get the results, which you need. For example the code

```
$grid.jqGrid("setGroupHeaders", {
    groupHeaders: [
        {startColumnName: "name", numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: "Main information"},
        {startColumnName: "amount", numberOfColumns: 5, titleText: "Details"}
    ]
})
.jqGrid("setGroupHeaders", {
    groupHeaders: [
        {startColumnName: "amount", numberOfColumns: 3, titleText: "<em>Price</em>"},
        {startColumnName: "closed", numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: "Shiping"}
    ]
});
```

create two level of column headers. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/8atan0o4/, which looks like on the picture below
[image]

Comment: It works! I didn't know that "setGroupHeaders" can be called multiple times. Now I got it :-))